# Get JSON object from list of keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is dynamically built that could look something like this:

```
my_dict = {"ministry": {
         "of": {
             "silly": {
                 "walks": {}
                 }
             }
          },
    "foo": "bar",
    "spam": {
        "ministry": {
            "of": "silly"
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I have a list of keys that is the address to the object I want to find that looks like this:

```
my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly", "walks"]
```

What would be the best way to use the my_keys to get to the position in my_dict. While there I also want to add to a new entry.

Been thinking and googling around for days but have not found anything, only think I can think of is remake it as a XML object.

I want to do something like

```
my_dict[my_keys[0]][my_keys[1]][my_keys[2]][my_keys[3]] = {"new":"entry"}
```

But I never know how many items are in the my_keys list. How would you guys solve this?

---

**Edit 1:**
Based on [Pauls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478322/3510201) answer I did this

```
def get(json_object, path):
    if type(path) == str:
        path = path.split(".")

    if type(path) != list or len(path) == 0:
        return

    key = path.pop(0)

    if len(path) == 0:
        try:
            return json_object[key]
        except KeyError:
            return

    if len(path):
        return get(json_object[key], path)
```

Which is then used like this:

```
my_found_item = get(my_dict, my_keys)
if my_found_item:
    my_found_item["new"] = "entry"

print(my_dict)
```

Which works if my_keys are like this:

```
my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly"]
```

But if my_keys goes all the way down like this it will not work

```
my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly", "walks"]

my_found_item = get(my_dict, my_keys)
if my_found_item:
    my_found_item["new"] = "entry"
```

Does anyone know how to fix that 'small' problem?

---

Edit 2
It is of course because I need to check if my_found_item is not none. This change fixes it:

```
if my_found_item is not None:
    my_found_item["new"] = "entry"
```

Answered my own question with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478778/3510201)

Comment: what do you mean by "to get to the position in my_dict. While there I also want to add to a new entry."

Comment: just keep going until the end of the my_keys

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu What I showed in the last code snippet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion.

The function you want has been written in a library for Javascript called [dotty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotty).  Now you can not simply copy and paste JS into python, you will need to do some translation.  The thing to notice here is the technique.

In particular they write a `.get()` function that will look deep in an object for a path defined with a string containing dots, like `ministry.of.silly.walks`

The implementation source code is [here](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty/blob/master/lib/index.js):

```
var get = module.exports.get = function get(object, path) {
  if (typeof path === "string") {
    path = path.split(".");
  }

  if (!(path instanceof Array) || path.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  path = path.slice();

  var key = path.shift();

  if (typeof object !== "object" || object === null) {
    return;
  }

  if (path.length === 0) {
    return object[key];
  }

  if (path.length) {
    return get(object[key], path);
  }
};
```

1. The function is designed to take either a string or an array as a parameter (`path`), and determine which it is.
2. The description string `ministry.of.silly.walks` is split on `.` to obtain an array that is stored in path (i.e. path is now set to `['ministry','of','silly','walks']`
3. The first element of `path` is removed with `path.shift()` and put in `key`, where it is used to access one level of the object (`object[key]`).
4. If the descriptor is out of levels (`path.length === 0`), we are done and have found the element (`object[key]`).  If not, we pass the reduced level object (`object[key]`) and the remaining part of the path array to access recursively back to get (`return get(object[key], path)`).

This recursive recipe should work in any language. I think you will find that python has `.shift()` and for `.slice()` you want to substitute a copy operation in python which could be `path = path[:]` or `path = copy.copy(path)`.  If you want to add new entries once the right spot in the object is found, then you'll need to add parameters for that and copy them down to recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the input you can build a string from the keys and use exec:

```
my_dict = {"ministry": {
         "of": {
             "silly": {
                 "walks": {}
                 }
             }
          },
    "foo": "bar",
    "spam": {
        "ministry": {
            "of": "silly"
            }
        }
    }

my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly", "walks"]


exec """my_dict{} = {{"new":"entry"}}""".format("".join(map("['{}']".format, my_keys)))
```

Demo:

```
In [47]: my_dict = {"ministry": {
         "of": {
             "silly": {
                 "walks": {}
                 }
             }
          },
    "foo": "bar",
    "spam": {
        "ministry": {
            "of": "silly"
            }
        }
    }

In [48]: my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly", "walks"]

In [49]: exec """my_dict{} = {{"new":"entry"}}""".format("".join(map("['{}']".format, my_keys)))

In [50]: my_dict
Out[50]: 
{'foo': 'bar',
 'ministry': {'of': {'silly': {'walks': {'new': 'entry'}}}},
 'spam': {'ministry': {'of': 'silly'}}}
```

If you also wanted to retrieve the value:

```
def pairing(d, new,keylist):
    path = "".join(map("['{}']".format, keylist))
    exec "get_val = d{}".format(path)
    exec "d{path} = {new}".format(new=new,path=path)
    return get_val
```

Demo:

```
In [58]: my_dict = {"ministry": {
     "of": {
         "silly": {
             "walks": {}
             }
         }
      },
"foo": "bar",
"spam": {
    "ministry": {
        "of": "silly"
        }
    }
}

In [59]: pairing(my_dict, {"new":"pairing"}, my_keys)
Out[59]: {}

In [60]: my_dict
Out[60]: 
{'foo': 'bar',
 'ministry': {'of': {'silly': {'walks': {'new': 'pairing'}}}},
 'spam': {'ministry': {'of': 'silly'}}}
```

If you pass the wrong key you will get a keyError as you would normally:

```
n [61]: my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly", "foo"]

In [62]: pairing(my_dict, {"new":"pairing"}, my_keys)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
...................
<string> in <module>()

KeyError: 'foo'
```

If you want you can use a `try/except` or `dict.get` as you would normally to catch any error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Pauls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478322/3510201) answer about the Javascript called dotty.

```
my_dict = {"ministry": {
         "of": {
             "silly": {
                 "walks": {}
                 }
             }
          },
    "foo": "bar",
    "spam": {
        "ministry": {
            "of": "silly"
            }
        }
    }

my_keys = ["ministry", "of", "silly"]


def get_json(json_object, path):
    __path = path[:]
    if type(__path) == str:
        __path = __path.split(".")

    if type(path) != list or len(__path) == 0:
        return

    key = __path.pop(0)

    if len(__path) == 0:
        try:
            return json_object[key]
        except KeyError:
            return

    if len(__path):
        return get_json(json_object[key], __path)

    my_found_item = get(my_dict, my_keys)
    if my_found_item is not None:
        my_found_item["new"] = "entry"

    print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Is there some indentation missing in the 2nd if statement? It looks like it should only run if the path is split, to abort if the split is incorrect.

Comment: @Paul I don't think so. It works fine if except in one case. I will update my original post with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonpointer](https://python-json-pointer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to access elements in a dictionary

```
from jsonpointer import resolve_pointer

my_pointer = '/' + '/'.join(my_keys)

resolve_pointer(my_dict, my_pointer)['new'] = 'entry'
```

**EDIT:**
 I just discovered [jsonpath.rw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw), looks even more powerful than jsonpointer